# Automatic population of an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup, formulas

I am looking to make a form in which you can pull down a menu and have fields populate based on your selection. On my excel workbook I have Sheet 1 which is the menu and Sheet 2 which has the data.

Sheet 1 is laid out as such

```
Item Code   Description    Wholesale Price     Retail Price
```

Sheet 2 is:

```
00001       Beans           0.45                0.67
```

I have setup a drop down list in A1 (Item Code) to reference the item code range on Sheet 2 but what I want to happen after I select the item code is for the rest of the information to populate. I have come close using VLOOKUP but I just don't seem to be able to nail it down.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In `Sheet1`:

```
B2 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10,2,FALSE)
C2 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10,3,FALSE)
D2 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10,4,FALSE)
```

Where:

- `Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10` is your reference table in `Sheet2`
- In `Sheet1` I assume you have a header row (hence A2, B2, C2, D2)

Comment: It's as simple as that! Thank you sir!!

Answer (score 1):

**Sheet 1**:
[image: Sheet 1]

Formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$D,2,FALSE)
```

Where

- `A2` is the range of the Item Code
- `Sheet2!$A:$D` is the 4 columns to look in for data
- `2`, `3` and `4` are the columns (within the above 4) of your desired data.
- `FALSE` requires it to be an exact match

**Sheet 2**:

[image: Sheet 2]

Result in sheet 1:

[image: Result]

Note: I've formatted the `A` columns as text to preserve the leading zeros, hence the little green triangles in the cell corners.